# Install the font when the application is running

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, textblock

I am developing a WPF C# program that shows some texts in a textblock with several fonts.
Font setting must be portable, so i save user selected font files next to program folder to load each time (in a static-name file).

```
var textFont = new FontFamily("file:///" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/themes/tmp/text/#" + textFontName);
```

1- how to change font file and set fontfamily from it realtime? (i set fontfamily from file but when it replaced with another font, textblock shows empty characters)

**Update:** a sample of my code: https://github.com/qwerty13/Wpf-local-font-bug

2- how to install missing font and use it realtime? I am using fontreg.exe but it requires Adminstrator access and restarting program to apply.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: @Derviş Kayımbaşıoğlu updated